# How can I rerender when object (a dictionary) changes?

Tags: ember.js, computed-properties, computed-observable, ember-classic

I have the following .hbs

```
<button {{action "addToObject"}}>
    Add to Object
</button>

<br />

{{#each this.sortedDictionary as |item|}}
    {{item.name}}<br />
{{/each}}
```

and the corresponding .js code for it:

```
import Component from '@ember/component';
import EmberObject, {set, computed, observer} from '@ember/object';

export default Component.extend(
{
    myDictionary: null,
    counter: 0,



    init()
    {
        this._super( ...arguments );

        console.log( "test-comp init" );

        this.myDictionary = {};

        set( this.myDictionary, "hello", "42" );
    },



    sortedDictionary: computed( 'myDictionary', function()
    {
        let sortedDictionary = [];

        if ( this.myDictionary ) 
        {
            const keys = Object.keys( this.myDictionary );

            keys.sort();

            console.log( "test-comp keys", keys );

            sortedDictionary = keys.reduce( ( sorted, itemName ) => 
            {
                const value = 
                {
                    name: itemName,
                    ...this.myDictionary[ itemName ]
                }

                sorted.push( value );

                return sorted;
            }, []);
        }

        console.log( "test-comp sortedDictionary", sortedDictionary );

        return sortedDictionary;
    }),



    actions:
    {
        addToObject()
        {
            set( this.myDictionary, `hello${this.counter}`, "42" );

            this.counter++;

            console.log( "test-comp addToObject", this.myDictionary );
        }
    }
});
```

In my mind, when I press the **Add to Object** button, my .hbs should rerender. However, it does not.

I am assuming this is because **sortedDictionary** is not recomputed and cannot detect that **myDictionary** has changed.

What is the correct solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your ember computed function, only dependency is `myDictionary`. So computed will fire only theres a reference change to `myDictionary` object. You can tweak this by calling dictionary event change or adding another dependency which changes when firing the action (in your example, `counter`). If you are using `counter` as a dependency for the computed property, you have to use `set` function to trigger dependency change.

In addition to that, hbs doesn't need to have `this` to get `myDictionary` since it uses related component as its context

Comment: What is "calling dictionary event change"?

Comment: Calling `notifyPropertyChange` function. In your case it should be `this.notifyPropertyChange('myDictionary')`

Comment: Thank you for the additional information. According to the ember documentation, there are methods for watch internal changes to arrays ( array.[], @each ). But, based on your answer, no similar methods are available for watching internal changes to maps (i.e. dictionarys) ... is this correct? One must be aware of when such internal changes take place and either (1) call notifyPropertyChange or (2) add an additional dependency as you mentioned above. Correct?

Comment: Based on further investigation, the answer to both questions is "YES". However, for newer versions of Ember, is an addon that extends autotracking to JS collections https://github.com/tracked-tools/tracked-built-ins ... it offers TrackedMap which would resolve this problem as well.

Comment: I was't aware about this addon. Thank you for the link. I usually use a computed array (sorted) from a dictionary